# Do the three slots in the Abbey and Tavern give different amounts of stress relief?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

So, when you want to de-stress your characters between dungeons, you can chooose between the Abbey or the Tavern. Both have 3 slots available, which cost 1000 gp, 1250gp, and 1500gp.

I know that sometimes there are reasons you'd choose a higher-cost slot (such as if the lower ones are full, or your character has a quirk preventing their use), but, assuming you haven't purchased building upgrades to upgrade any slot yeah, is there any stress-relief difference between the 1000 gp slot and the 1500 gp slot? Does this change once you get all the slots fully upgraded?

Basically, I'm wondering if (building upgrades aside) I should just always dump my characters into the cheapest stress-relief slots available, even if some characters have more stress than others.

Comment: The LP I watched mentioned that the ones further down relieved more stress, but since I haven't played or tested myself, I'll hold off on actually answering.

Comment: I think I saw the same LP, but the one time I put a guy in the expensive slot, he only cured 46 stress versus the cheapest guy's 42 stress, and every visit to the lower place seems to heal 40-50. So while the one time I tested it it happened to be more (by 4), I'm not sure the LP guy had it right. For a 50% price increase I would have expected to see a larger jump.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To the research!

I started a new game, mentaly broke a few adventurers and sent them to the unupgraded tavern and abbey. Later, after a coulple of rounds, I tested once upgraded slots. The results:

**Bar/Meditation:** Level 1: 45 stress, Level 2: 56 stress
**Gambling/Prayer:** Level 1: 55 stress, Level 2: 69 stress
**Brothel/Penance:** Level 1: 65 stress, Level 2: 81 stress

The numbers seem pretty consistant.

Tested on build 7614. As the game is in Early Access, these may change at any time.

Comment: Interesting. I could have sworn I saw some variability in mine, but maybe I was just sending a guy who had less than the maximum curable stress amount left. Thanks for the Science!